# Potential PhD applicant contacts me, mentions someone I know, can I contact such colleague?

Tags: phd, ethics, application, recommendation-letter

A potential PhD applicant has contacted me for an informal chat about a PhD project I am offering. The candidate mentions he wrote an MSc dissertation under the supervision of Prof. X. I happen to know Prof. X, and I was wondering if I can contact my colleague and ask for an informal reference on the potential applicant before suggesting moving forward with the application?

Are there any ethical impediments for doing so?

Comment: What country? .

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Does this affect the *ethical* implications?

Comment: @user151413 Well, certainly. Ethics aren't culture-neutral, especially for something as minor as contacting a professor about a professional recommendation (I'd almost object to including "ethics" in this question at all).

Comment: @Azor Yes, I think in my subconcious my comment was really more driven by the contrast of the minority (minor-ness?) of the issue (which makes it in principle cultural-specific) and the use of "ethics". (I did also upvote it, for what it's worth.)

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**

Chances are the potential PhD applicant expects you to contact them. That's why they're mentioning them! In fact it's possible Professor X recommended the student contact you.

Besides, even in the (in my opinion very unlikely) event that the student doesn't want you to contact their MSc supervisor immediately, they should know that you will need to contact their MSc supervisor eventually. After all, recommendation letters are a staple of PhD applications, and the thesis advisor is an obvious letter-writer.

Comment: But the student has not submitted a recommendation letter. The OP can ask for a recommendation letter from the student, and if what you're speculating about the intent of the student is actually true, the student will probably ask their master's supervisor to write the letter. 
I think in any case, the OP should ask the student or give them a chance to bring it up, if they want their master's supervisor to be contacted regarding this. 
And if the master's supervisor had in fact recommended the position to the student, the student can mention that, given the chance or if asked about that.

Comment: This is a facile but dangerous suggestion. "Chances are" is no basis on which to act. The ethical fault would be with the advisor who would respond, of course, but you have no business asking for something improper. The student has rights and you don't want to stomp on them. You are saying "all is fine because __maybe__  something something something." No. No. Please. I realize it is what you may want to hear, but it is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This is a US centric answer. It sounds like the professor's name was only mentioned in passing. It might be different if the potential student said that the professor actually asked you to make contact. But even then it is a bit dicey.

It would be improper for that professor to talk to you without the student's permission for the usual reasons of privacy. If you contact them "out of band" you would put them in an uncomfortable position and if they don't recognize the conflict then it might be worse.

You could, instead, ask the student to ask that professor to contact you. Or you could ask the student for permission to contact the professor and then communicate that permission to the professor. Respect the student's privacy rights.

If not the US then the same ethical rules apply, I hope, though they might be supported by law or not.

Answer (score -3):

Don't reach out before the interview.

In regular workplace interactions, such a reference is usually performed when the applicant has given consent to such an inquiry with a previous employer. Now this is not the exact same situation, but I would have a chat with the student before asking their supervisor, and ask the student whether they are okay with that.

This way, you will have an unbiased view of the student. You do not know the relationship that the student had with their former supervisor, but this way a negative (or positive!) opinion will not influence your first impression of the student. If the student is not okay with this request, by the way, this might also already give you some information.

Comment: I'm a student, and have never been on the other side of this story, but II have a hard time understanding the down votes to this answer.
Perhaps I'd say even after the interview, it might not be ok to contact the supervisor (see Buffy's answer), but still I don't understand the downvotes. Can someone please explain?!